# How to deal with sequence in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions, row-number

I have a question handling sequence in SQL Server.

I want to get result01.

Here is sample table.

```
CREATE TABLE temp01
(
    SEQ         int,
    cat01       numeric(6,0),
    cat02       numeric(6,0),
    dt_day      date,
    dt_week     date,
    dt_month    date,
    price       decimal(10,0)
)

INSERT INTO temp01 VALUES (1, 230, 1, '2019-01-01', '2019-01-05', '2019-01-31', 16000)
INSERT INTO temp01 VALUES (2, 230, 1, '2019-01-02', '2019-01-05', '2019-01-31', NULL)
INSERT INTO temp01 VALUES (3, 230, 1, '2019-01-03', '2019-01-05', '2019-01-31', 13000)
INSERT INTO temp01 VALUES (4, 230, 1, '2019-01-04', '2019-01-05', '2019-01-31', NULL)
INSERT INTO temp01 VALUES (5, 230, 1, '2019-01-05', '2019-01-12', '2019-01-31', NULL)
INSERT INTO temp01 VALUES (6, 230, 1, '2019-01-06', '2019-01-12', '2019-01-31', NULL)
INSERT INTO temp01 VALUES (7, 230, 1, '2019-01-07', '2019-01-12', '2019-01-31', 19000)
INSERT INTO temp01 VALUES (1, 230, 2, '2019-01-01', '2019-01-05', '2019-01-31', NULL)
INSERT INTO temp01 VALUES (2, 230, 2, '2019-01-02', '2019-01-05', '2019-01-31', NULL)
INSERT INTO temp01 VALUES (3, 230, 2, '2019-01-03', '2019-01-12', '2019-01-31', 12000)
INSERT INTO temp01 VALUES (4, 230, 2, '2019-01-04', '2019-01-12', '2019-01-31', 17000)
INSERT INTO temp01 VALUES (5, 230, 2, '2019-01-05', '2019-01-12', '2019-01-31', 22000)
INSERT INTO temp01 VALUES (6, 230, 2,' 2019-01-06', '2019-01-12', '2019-01-31', NULL)
INSERT INTO temp01 VALUES (7, 230, 2,' 2019-01-07', '2019-01-12', '2019-01-31', 21000)
```

And I want to get this table from temp01.

[result01]

```
    | SEQ | cat01 | cat02 |   dt_day   | price | sub_seq |
    | --- | ----- | ----- | ---------- | ----- | ------- |
    |  1  |  230  |   1   | 2019-01-01 | 16000 |    1    |
    |  3  |  230  |   1   | 2019-01-03 | 13000 |    2    |
    |  7  |  230  |   1   | 2019-01-07 | 19000 |    3    |
    |  3  |  230  |   2   | 2019-01-03 | 12000 |    1    |
    |  4  |  230  |   2   | 2019-01-04 | 17000 |    2    |    
    |  5  |  230  |   2   | 2019-01-05 | 22000 |    3    | 
    |  7  |  230  |   2   | 2019-01-07 | 21000 |    4    |
```

....

So, I use this code. I think this code incorrect.

```
WITH ROW_VALUE AS
(
    SELECT SEQ
        , dt_day
        , cat01
        , cat02
        , price
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY cat01, cat02, dt_day) AS sub_seq
    FROM (
        SELECT SEQ
            , cat01
            , cat02
            , dt_day
            , dt_week
            , dt_month
            , price
        FROM temp01
        WHERE price IS NOT NULL
            )val
)
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM ROW_VALUE
ORDER BY cat01, cat02, dt_day
```

How can I get a result01 table?

Please, review my code.

Comment: But, it can't extract result01 - ??Please clarify .Also if this sqlserver please remove mysql tag

Comment: Please explain the logic you want to implement.  It really isn't obvious from:  " I want to know that extract subsequences from repeated values.".

Comment: @P.Salmon Sorry about that. I want to get result01 table. I think this code incorrect.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yes, I want to get result01 table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should `PARTITION BY cat01, cat02` and `ORDER BY dt_day`:

```
SELECT SEQ
    , cat01
    , cat02
    , dt_day
    , dt_week
    , dt_month
    , price
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cat01, cat02 ORDER BY dt_day) AS sub_seq
FROM temp01
WHERE price IS NOT NULL
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=be51aab93db8ae036cfe07ea8e451ff0).
Results:

| SEQ | cat01 | cat02 | dt_day | dt_week | dt_month | price | sub_seq |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 230 | 1 | 2019-01-01 | 2019-01-05 | 2019-01-31 | 16000 | 1 |
| 3 | 230 | 1 | 2019-01-03 | 2019-01-05 | 2019-01-31 | 13000 | 2 |
| 7 | 230 | 1 | 2019-01-07 | 2019-01-12 | 2019-01-31 | 19000 | 3 |
| 3 | 230 | 2 | 2019-01-03 | 2019-01-12 | 2019-01-31 | 12000 | 1 |
| 4 | 230 | 2 | 2019-01-04 | 2019-01-12 | 2019-01-31 | 17000 | 2 |
| 5 | 230 | 2 | 2019-01-05 | 2019-01-12 | 2019-01-31 | 22000 | 3 |
| 7 | 230 | 2 | 2019-01-07 | 2019-01-12 | 2019-01-31 | 21000 | 4 |